# squid url_regex not working

Tags: server, proxy, squid

I'm using squid on our Citrix Servers as Proxy Server and only some domains are allowed.

But now I want only the URL  https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/seed/seed_consultation.jsp?Lang=fr to be allowed.

I made the following config

```
acl seed_url url_regex ^http(s)?://([a-zA-Z]+).ec.europa.eu//taxation_customs/dds2/seed/.*$
http_access allow seed_url
```

But it do not work squid give the answer in the log

```
1681897274.439      0 x.x.x.x TCP_DENIED/403 4083 CONNECT ec.europa.eu:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

Any idea to only allow this URL ?